# How to align columns with multiple phantom characters?

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, alignment, phantom

I couldn't figure how to align a column containing `{ 1.00, -1.00, 10.00, 0.00 }`.

I aligned the first two using `\phantom{-}` and the last two using `\phantom{1}` but failed to align all 4 lines at once.

[image]

Sample code (problem is in the last matrix block):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
                   -1.00\\
        \phantom{-} 1.00\\
        \phantom{-} 1.00
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{1} 1.00\\
                   10.00\\
        \phantom{1} 0.00
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{-} 0.00\\
                   -1.00\\
                   10.00\\
        \phantom{1} 0.00
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related: You do not need any longer `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in modern LaTeX distributions.

Comment: @F.Pantigny : Thanks. It comes with the "Wizard > Quick Start" menu of Texmaker.

Comment: Load `mathtools` in the place of `amsmath` and use `\begin{bmatrix*}[r] … \end{bmatrix*}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to solve that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
       -1.00\\
        1.00\\
        1.00
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
        1.00\\
       10.00\\
        0.00
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
        0.00\\
       -1.00\\
       10.00\\
        0.00
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` writes informations on the `aux` file).

[image: Output of the above code]